# Mostrar imágenes en mi sitio web que tengo en mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Ayer a la noche viendo una guía, pude hacer un sistema muy básico en el que puedo subir mis imágenes a mysql desde un apartado en el sitio web. Esto lo hice viendo una guía en internet.

El problema está en que yo puedo subir imágenes, pero no sé cómo poder mostrarlas en mi sitio web.

Yo tengo una estructura y un diseño listo para mostrar lo que son las imágenes:

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
}

main h2.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

main .galeria {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.473);
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

main .galeria .container-img {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

main .galeria .container-img img {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

main .galeria .container-img h5 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h2 class="title">Imagenes de nuestros trabajos</h2>
    
    
    <section class="galeria">
        <div class="container-img">
            <img src="https://elcomercio.pe/resizer/LVxIhRU2aZ2htjhQuSR8SVx72jM=/980x0/smart/filters:format(jpeg):quality(75)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-elcomercio.s3.amazonaws.com/public/6BNTDLVEWNEN3A7CHKMJL36JVQ.jpg" alt="">
            <h5>Titulo de la imagen</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
            <img src="https://elcomercio.pe/resizer/LVxIhRU2aZ2htjhQuSR8SVx72jM=/980x0/smart/filters:format(jpeg):quality(75)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-elcomercio.s3.amazonaws.com/public/6BNTDLVEWNEN3A7CHKMJL36JVQ.jpg" alt="">
            <h5>Titulo de la imagen</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
            <img src="https://elcomercio.pe/resizer/LVxIhRU2aZ2htjhQuSR8SVx72jM=/980x0/smart/filters:format(jpeg):quality(75)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-elcomercio.s3.amazonaws.com/public/6BNTDLVEWNEN3A7CHKMJL36JVQ.jpg" alt="">
            <h5>Titulo de la imagen</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
            <img src="https://elcomercio.pe/resizer/LVxIhRU2aZ2htjhQuSR8SVx72jM=/980x0/smart/filters:format(jpeg):quality(75)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-elcomercio.s3.amazonaws.com/public/6BNTDLVEWNEN3A7CHKMJL36JVQ.jpg" alt="">
            <h5>Titulo de la imagen</h5>
        </div>


    </section>
</main>
```

Después tengo lo que es mi *cargar.php* que está de la siguiente forma:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        /*
         * Insert image data into database
         */
        
        //DB details
        $dbHost     = 'localhost';
        $dbUsername = 'root';
        $dbPassword = '';
        $dbName     = 'ryb';
        
        //Create connection and select DB
        $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
        
        // Check connection
        if($db->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
        }
        
        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        
        //Insert image content into database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT into galeria (image, created) VALUES ('$imgContent', '$dataTime')");
        if($insert){
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        }else{
            echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
        } 
    }else{
        echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
    }
}
```

Esto funciona a la perfección, las imágenes se guardan en mi base de datos de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En lo que es mi archivo *galeria.php*, tengo lo siguiente:

```
 $result = $db->query("SELECT image FROM galeria WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}");
    
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();
        //Render image
        header("Content-type: image/jpg"); 
        echo $imgData['image']; 
    }else{
        echo 'Image not found...';
    }
}
```

Pero las imágenes que yo subo, no aparecen en ningún lado de la página.

Comment: Ese echo $imgData no te va a mostrar la imagen, añade la etiqueta <img> antes, y luego si pásale el valor que traes en el result

Answer (score 0):

las estas almacenando en base x64 lo ideal sería subir el archivo a una carpeta del server y guardar en la BD lod datos de dicha imagen ('nombre', 'url', 'tipo de archivo', etc...)

comienzo en el `if`:

```
if($check !== false){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imgContent = addslashes($image);
    //lista de estenciones de imágenes para verificar.
    $img = array ('.jpg','.png','.gif','.ico','.btm');
     //verificamos si hay más de un archivo y las extenciónes de cada uno
     foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $keys => $values){
      $titulo = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $ext = substr($values, strrpos($values, '.'));
      if (in_array($ext, $img)){
        // verificamos si se movieron los archivos y los subimos a la BD
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$keys], '../media/images/' .$titulo.$ext)){
        $url = '../media/images/' .$titulo.$ext;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (nombre, url, etc..) VALUES ($image, $url, etc)";
        $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
      }
     }else{
       $msg = "Lo sentimos archivo no permitido";
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Cómo hago eso? Hay alguna guía?

Comment: modifica la BD con los campos que creas nesesarios puedes seguir el ejemplo que deje arriba para hacerla y luego pasa los datos de la imagen subida al `querry($sql);`, si me dejas el codigo que estas usando para subir las imagenes te lo puedo modificar para hacerlo.

Comment: Ahi edito la publicacion y pongo el codigo completo que utilizo para subir las imagenes

Comment: comienzo en el `if`:

Comment: Si quieres puedes ponerlo en la respuesta, asi no tienes que estar comentando todo, agradezco enormemente tu ayuda Carlos

Comment: bueno ya edite la respuesta si tienes dudas o errores solo escribeme montero9308@gmail.com

Comment: Hola Carlos, gracias por la respuesta, pegue eso en mi codigo y me salieron muchos errores, pero: ¿Por que deberia modificar esa parte del codigo, si es la unica que funciona? yo quiero poner las fotos que subo en la base de datos

Comment: bueno por lo general es `buena praxis` hacerlo de esa manera ya que las imágenes en base x64 usan mucho espacio en la BD y la ralentizan solo se recomienda usarlo cuando sean imágenes pequeñas como iconos, emojis o un recorte de una imagen algo pequeño. Manda los errores por mi correo o pasamos el tema al chat y ahi lo dicutimos

Comment: Dale, si quieres puedo crear un chat

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131320/discussion-between-hatori-hanso-and-carlos-arias-montero).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131320/discussion-between-hatori-hanso-and-carlos-arias-montero