# Poner imagenes en html guardadas en mysql con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy intentando hacer un sistema en el que un usuario pueda subir una imagen con un titulo en un panel de control, y
esa imagen se vea en otro archivo .php llamado galeria.php.

El problema esta en que pude subir las imagenes desde el panel de control a mysql, pero no se como mostrarlas en la galeria.

El codigo para subir las imagenes es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
  include("conexion.php");
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

        echo $titulo;
        
        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        
        //Insert image content into database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT into galeria (image, created, titulo) VALUES ('$imgContent', '$dataTime', '$titulo')");
        if($insert){
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        }else{
            echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
        } 
    }else{
        echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
    }
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="backend.css">
    <title>
        Subir imagenes
    </title>
</head>

    
<body>
    <form action="cargar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="container">
            <label>Seleccionar imagen para subir</label>
            <input type="file" name="image"/>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo" id="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

¿Como puedo mostrar las imagenes en el html?

Ya tengo lo que es la estructura donde las quiero dejar listas,

estaria bueno poder mostrarlas usando forEach, asi se publican en fila.

Gracias

Comment: ¿[Misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/496278/mostrar-imágenes-en-mi-sitio-web-que-tengo-en-mi-base-de-datos)?

Comment: Hola Sal, la pregunta anterior la elimine

Answer (score 0):

Primero haces un `select` de las imágenes del usuario o todas,no se que filtro usaras. eso te dará como resultado un `array` luego:

**galeria.php**

```html
<?php
//esta seria la lista de imagenes que deberias rellenar con el resultado del select
$listaImagenes =[];


//recorremos la lista
foreach($listaImagenes as $k => $imagen){
   $image = $imagen["imagen"];
   $created = $imagen["created"];
   $titulo = $imagen["titulo];


  echo "
   <div>
    <h3>$titulo - $created</h3>
    <img src="$imagen">
   </div>
  ";

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//<?php 
include("administrador/config/bd.php"); // conexion a mysql y base de datos
$sentenciaSQL=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla"); //donde tabla es el nombre de la tabla donde esta la imagen y los demas datos
$sentenciaSQL->execute();
$listatablas=$sentenciaSQL->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<table align="center">

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($listatablas as $listabla) {  ?>
        
            <tr>
            
            <td><?php echo $tabla["nombre"];?></td>//un campo de la tabla diferente a imagen
             <td >
            <img src="img/<?php echo $tabla["imagen"]; ?>" width="30%" alt="" srcset=""> //el campo imagen de la tabla donde esta la imagen 
            </td> 
            
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Código sin explicación tal vez sea útil al OP, pero a nadie más. Si agregas una explicación, una enseñanza para quienes no sabes, entonces sería una respuesta valiosa.

Comment: si tienes razon soy nuevo en esta plataforma